# rake task not running sub-tasks in order specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, bundler

In a rails 4.2 app, in Rakefile, I have this:

```
task(:default).clear
task :default => [:test, 'bundle:audit']
```

The output, always has bundle:audit running first.  Why is that?

I read in some places that rake executes tasks as dependencies arise, but bundle:audit, as far as I can tell, does not depend on test.  It is defined here:

https://github.com/rubysec/bundler-audit/blob/master/lib/bundler/audit/task.rb

Answer (score 0):

To quote a [comment](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/issues/385#issuecomment-64038170) discussing the same problem in Rake's GitHub repository:

> It turns out that your problem is due to the way rails creates its test tasks:
>
> ```
> desc "Run tests quickly by merging all types and not resetting db"
> Rails::TestTask.new(:all) do |t|
>   t.pattern = "test/**/*_test.rb"
> end
> ```
>
> https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.7.1/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake#L24-L27
>
> Here Rails uses Rails::TestTask for the `test:all` target which will load all test files.
>
> ```
> def define
>   task @name do
>     if ENV['TESTOPTS']
>       ARGV.replace Shellwords.split ENV['TESTOPTS']
>     end
>     libs = @libs - $LOAD_PATH
>     $LOAD_PATH.unshift(*libs)
>     file_list.each { |fl|
>       FileList[fl].to_a.each { |f| require File.expand_path f }
>     }
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.7.1/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb#L106-L118
>
> But unlike Rake::TestTask, which immediately runs the tests, Rails::TestTask only requires the files necessary to run the tests then relies on the `at_exit` handler in Minitest to run the tests. This means rake dependencies are completely ignored for running tests.

I updated the links to the source code, because the discussion was about Rails 4.1.8, but the problem still exists the source code of Rails 4.2.7.1.

This problem was reported as an [issue to the Rails team](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17708) on GitHub and it was fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19571).

That said: This problem should be fixed since Rails 5.0.0.